# Why doesn't my Bootstrap text fields line up with my bullet points?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html-lists

Why don't my `form-control` text fields line up with my bullet points? There are no styles or margins or padding at the top which would force it down. I also tried using `.w-75` on the `<li>` but it didn't help.

https://www.bootply.com/ZWMAT3qhgo#

Bootstrap 4 alpha 6

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding `.d-inline` to the `<input>` and `.my-1` to the `<li>` for spacing.

[image]

```
%ul
  %li.my-1= cf.text_field :bullet1, placeholder: 'Bullet point #1', class: 'form-control d-inline', 'data-toggle': 'tooltip'
  %li.my-1= cf.text_field :bullet2, placeholder: 'Bullet point #2', class: 'form-control d-inline', 'data-toggle': 'tooltip'
```